# Authorization library on Symfony HttpFoundation Component

Tags: php, authentication, symfony

Can anyone knows a library to authenticate users using Symfony HttpFondation Component?

PS Symfony Security Component is not suitable, as too big.
PPS Project does not using Symfony Framework.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you think the security component is too big?  Sure it has a bunch of stuff in it but it seems like you could pull out the TokenInterface, UserInterface, AuthenticationProvider and UserProvider without much effort.  What exactly do you want the system to do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any (at this time).

[PPI framework](https://github.com/ppi/framework) uses some of the Symfony components (also HttpFoundation). See how they solved it. Otherwise you'd probably need to handle it yourself.